# HTML Table cell background image alignment

Tags: html, css

I need the background image of a table cell to be aligned as

> Top in vertical side - Right in Horizontal

But it is displaying as,

> Center in Vertical side ; Right in Horizontal

Take a look at this page: http://www.chemfluence.org.in/monetarist/index_copy.php

Here is my code,

```
<td width="178" rowspan="3" valign="top" 
align="right" background="images/left.jpg" 
style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right;">
</td>
```

if i use **background-position:Top;** it is center aligned Horizontally
please let me know which should be corrected.

Comment: have a look at this for setting background. http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use like this your inline css

```
<td width="178" rowspan="3" valign="top" 
align="right" background="images/left.jpg" 
style="background-repeat:background-position: right top;">
</td>
```

Comment: have you applied this, I have checked this

Answer (score 6):

This works in IE9 (Compatibility View and Normal Mode), Firefox 17, and Chrome 23:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url(untitled.png); background-position:right 0px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
            Hello World
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```